# Run SSIS package from VB6

Tags: vb6, ssis

Can anyone tell me how can I run a SSIS package from VB6?

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim dtsApp As Application
Dim package As IDTSPackage90

Set dtsApp = New Application

Set package = dtsApp.LoadPackage("c:\MyPackage.dtsx", True, Nothing)

package.Execute
```

You need to add a reference to Microsoft DTS Runtime 1.0. It should be located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTS.dll

Answer (score 3):

You can call [dtexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx) from the command line:

```
    Private Sub CmdRun_Click()
       Dim result
       result = Shell("dtexec /f c:\mypackage.dtsx", vbNormalFocus)
    End Sub
```